# Fetch data from API and show in Dropdownlist, click on option show data

Tags: javascript, html, api

I'm still learning javascript and need little help.

Project is about display data from API in dropdown list, what I already did, and its working.

API LINK: http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions

I want someone to help me with code, when you click on some value inside box, to display data for that ID

Example:

Dropdownlist showing data by:

> caption

and every "caption" has unique ID, Example:

> id: 444,
> caption: "Campeonato Brasileiro da Série A",

When I click on that option to show me TEAMS from that Football League.

Teams are in separate link:

> http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/444/teams

I do not know how from here?!

```js
let dropdown = document.getElementById('locality-dropdown');
dropdown.length = 0;

let defaultOption = document.createElement('option');
defaultOption.text = 'Choose...';

dropdown.add(defaultOption);
dropdown.selectedIndex = 0;

const url = 'http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions';

fetch(url)  
  .then(  
    function(response) {  
      if (response.status !== 200) {  
        console.warn('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' + 
          response.status);  
        return;  
      }

      // Examine the text in the response  
      response.json().then(function(data) {  
        let option;
    
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          option = document.createElement('option');
            option.text = data[i].caption;
            option.value = data[i].id;
          dropdown.add(option);
        }
        
        });

        }  
  )  
  .catch(function(err) {  
    console.error('Fetch Error -', err);  
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <title>Football-Data API</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        
         
</head>
<body>
        <div class="container">
                <h1 class="display-4 mb-4">www.football-data.org</h1>
                <div class="d-flex">
                  <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="sel1">Select competitions:</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="locality-dropdown" onchange=(myFunction)>
                          <option></option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div id="output"></div>
              </div>
            
</body>
</html>
```

[example scrnshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8Qe8.jpg)

Comment: Is something not working in your code? Is it showing any errors?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: again API TOKEN forgot to put, code is working, but I do not know how to do from here, when you click on one competition, to show Teams, example "getStandings ()" for each option in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code show all team in the selected league.

```js
let dropdown = document.getElementById('locality-dropdown');
    var teamList = document.getElementById("output");

    dropdown.length = 0;

    let defaultOption = document.createElement('option');
    defaultOption.text = 'Choose...';

    dropdown.add(defaultOption);
    dropdown.selectedIndex = 0;

    const url = 'http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions';

    fetch(url)  
      .then(  
        function(response) {  
          if (response.status !== 200) {  
            console.warn('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' + 
              response.status);  
            return;  
          }

          // Examine the text in the response  
          response.json().then(function(data) {  
            let option;
        
         for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
              option = document.createElement('option');
                option.text = data[i].caption;
                option.value = data[i].id;
             dropdown.add(option);
            }
            
            });

            }  
      )  
      .catch(function(err) {  
        console.error('Fetch Error -', err);  
      });

      function myFunction(e){
        teamList.innerHTML = "";

        //Get selected league id
        var leagueId = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;        
        
        fetch(`http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions/${leagueId}/teams`)  
      .then(  
        function(response) {  
          if (response.status !== 200) {  
            console.warn('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' + 
              response.status);  
            return;  
          }

          response.json().then(function(data) { 
            //iterate over each team 
            data.teams.forEach(team =>{
                var p = document.createElement("p");
                p.innerHTML = team.name; //Add team name to a p element
                teamList.appendChild(p);  
            });
            
            });

            }  
      )  
      .catch(function(err) {  
        console.error('Fetch Error -', err);  
      });

      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
            <title>Football-Data API</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            
             
    </head>
    <body>
            <div class="container">
                    <h1 class="display-4 mb-4">www.football-data.org</h1>
                    <div class="d-flex">
                      <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="sel1">Select competitions:</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="locality-dropdown" onchange="myFunction(this);">
                              <option></option>
                            </select>
                          </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div id="output"></div>
                  </div>
                
    </body>
    </html>
```